# Sparse Bitarray Class in Python (or rather frequently having contiguous elements with the same value)

Tags: python, array

Sparse is probably the wrong word - this is for encoding arrays of booleans where contiguous values tend to be the same. It'd be great to know a proper name for this data structure so I could read about it or use an existing implementation. I already realize I probably ought not to use doctest, and would welcome feedback on this as well. [github](https://github.com/thomasballinger/bittorrent/blob/74fc610a4a669ee2201ffd0ca70f2d9335e6c367/sparsebitarray.py)

```
"""
Sparse (really Frequently Contiguous) Binary Array

TODO:
bitwise and would be really useful
generalize to more than two possible values
binary search to find overlapping segments

"""
class SBA(object):
    """Sparse BitArray, in which data is represented by ranges

    >>> s = SBA(20); s
    <SparseBitArray of length 20, all bits cleared>
    """
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
        self.set_ranges = []
    def __len__(self):
        return self.length
    def __repr__(self):
        s = '<SparseBitArray of length %d, ' % self.length
        if not self.set_ranges:
            s += 'all bits cleared>'
        elif self.set_ranges == [(0, self.length)]:
            s += 'all bits set>'
        else:
            s += str(self.set_ranges)+'>'
        return s
    def _find_overlapping_ranges(self, start, end):
        """Returns existing ranges that overlap or touch a new one

        Returns a tuple of
          * ranges entirely contained by the new start and end
          * ranges over or at the edge of the new start and end
          * the range, if any, that entirely contains the new start and end
        """
        #TODO use binary search instead here
        edge_overlapping = []
        contained_by_new = []
        contains_new = None
        for r_start, r_end in self.set_ranges:
            if r_end < start or r_start > end:
                pass
            elif r_start <= start and r_end >= end:
                contains_new = (r_start, r_end)
                break
            elif r_start >= start and r_end <= end:
                contained_by_new.append((r_start, r_end))
            elif start <= r_start <= end or start <= r_end <= end:
                edge_overlapping.append((r_start, r_end))
            else:
                raise Exception("Logic Error!")
        return contained_by_new, edge_overlapping, contains_new

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """Get a slice or the value of an entry

        >>> s = SBA(20); s[2:6] = True; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(2, 6)]>
        >>> s[2:6]
        <SparseBitArray of length 4, all bits set>
        >>> s[4:10]
        <SparseBitArray of length 6, [(0, 2)]>
        >>> s[9:14] = True; s[17:19] = True; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(2, 6), (9, 14), (17, 19)]>
        >>> s[2:18]
        <SparseBitArray of length 16, [(0, 4), (7, 12), (15, 16)]>
        >>> s[1], s[10]
        (False, True)
        """
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            start, step, end = key.start, key.step, key.stop
            if start is None: start = 0
            if end is None: end = len(self)
            if step not in [None, 1]: raise ValueError("Custom steps not allowed: "+repr(key))
            contained_by, edge_overlaps, contains = self._find_overlapping_ranges(start, end)
            result = SBA(end - start)
            if contains:
                result[:] = True
            for r_start, r_end in contained_by:
                result.set_ranges.append((r_start - start, r_end - start))
            for overlap_start, overlap_end in edge_overlaps:
                if overlap_end == start or overlap_start == end:
                    pass
                elif overlap_end < end:
                    result.set_ranges.append((0, overlap_end - start))
                elif overlap_start > start:
                    result.set_ranges.append((overlap_start - start, end - start))
                else:
                    raise Exception("Logic Error!")
            return result
        else:
            contained_by, edge_overlaps, contains = self._find_overlapping_ranges(key, key+1)
            if contained_by or contains:
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """Sets item or slice to True or False

        >>> s = SBA(20); s[2:6] = True; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(2, 6)]>
        >>> s[4:10] = True; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(2, 10)]>
        >>> s[3:11] = False; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(2, 3)]>
        >>> s[4:14] = True; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(2, 3), (4, 14)]>
        >>> s[8:11] = False; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(2, 3), (4, 8), (11, 14)]>
        >>> s[5:7] = True; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(2, 3), (4, 8), (11, 14)]>
        >>> s[15:18] = False; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(2, 3), (4, 8), (11, 14)]>
        >>> s[14:16] = False; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(2, 3), (4, 8), (11, 14)]>
        >>> s[14:16] = True; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(2, 3), (4, 8), (11, 16)]>
        >>> s[4:] = True; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(2, 3), (4, 20)]>
        >>> s[:10] = False; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, [(10, 20)]>
        >>> s[:] = False; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, all bits cleared>
        >>> s[:] = True; s
        <SparseBitArray of length 20, all bits set>
        """
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            start, step, end = key.start, key.step, key.stop
            if start is None: start = 0
            if end is None: end = len(self)
            if step not in [None, 1]: raise ValueError("Custom steps not allowed: "+repr(key))
            contained_by, edge_overlaps, contains = self._find_overlapping_ranges(start, end)
            if contains:
                if not value:
                    self.set_ranges.remove(contains)
                    self.set_ranges.append((contains[0], start))
                    self.set_ranges.append((end, contains[1]))
                return
            if value:
                for overlap_start, overlap_end in edge_overlaps:
                    if overlap_start < start:
                        start = overlap_start
                        self.set_ranges.remove((overlap_start, overlap_end))
                    elif overlap_end > end:
                        end = overlap_end
                        self.set_ranges.remove((overlap_start, overlap_end))
                    else:
                        raise Exception("Logic Error!")
            else:
                for overlap_start, overlap_end in edge_overlaps:
                    if overlap_start < start:
                        self.set_ranges.remove((overlap_start, overlap_end))
                        self.set_ranges.append((overlap_start, start))
                    elif overlap_end > end:
                        self.set_ranges.remove((overlap_start, overlap_end))
                        self.set_ranges.append((end, overlap_end))
                    else:
                        raise Exception("Logic Error!")
            for set_range in contained_by:
                self.set_ranges.remove(set_range)
            if value:
                self.set_ranges.append((start, end))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Single element assignment not allowed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    print doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your `__repr__` function tells the outside world about the implementation of your class. The fact that you are using a particular internal representation of a string shouldn't be exposed even here. I suggest this function should return something of the form `SparseBitArray('1111')` instead.
2. `_find_overlapping_ranges` doesn't seem very useful. Every time it is used, there some tricky to follow logic regarding it afterwards.
3. The logic for decoding the slice is duplicated in `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, refactor it into a function
4. `__getitem__` doesn't raise IndexError for out of bounds indexes. This would make it iterable.
5. Your internal data structure isn't actually the best choice. You store data like [(4, 7), (10, 25)]. Each tuple indicates a range of 1 values. A better approach would actually be to hold [4, 8, 10, 25], where each value indicates a point at which the bitstring changes from 1 to 0 or vice versa.

My reworking of your code:

```
import bisect
import sys

class SBA(object):
    """Sparse BitArray, in which data is represented by ranges

    >>> s = SBA(length = 20); s
    SparseBitArray('00000000000000000000')
    """
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
        self.set_ranges = []
        self.changes = []
    def __len__(self):
        return self.length
    def __repr__(self):
        text = ''.join(str(int(x)) for x in self)
        return "SparseBitArray('%s')" % text

    def _decode_slice(self, key):
        start, end = key.start, key.stop
        if start is None: start = 0
        if end is None: end = len(self)
        if key.step not in [None, 1]: raise ValueError("Custom steps not allowed: "+repr(key))

        return start, end


    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """Get a slice or the value of an entry

        >>> s = SBA(20); s[2:6] = True; s
        SparseBitArray('00111100000000000000')
        >>> s[2:6]
        SparseBitArray('1111')
        >>> s[4:10]
        SparseBitArray('110000')
        >>> s[9:14] = True; s[17:19] = True; s
        SparseBitArray('00111100011111000110')
        >>> s[2:18]
        SparseBitArray('1111000111110001')
        >>> s[1], s[10]
        (False, True)
        """
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            start, end = self._decode_slice(key)
            start_index, end_index = self._indexes(start, end)
            result = SBA(end - start)

            if self[start]:
                result.changes.append(0)

            result.changes.extend( 
                change - start for change in self.changes[start_index:end_index] )

            return result
        else:
            if key >= len(self):
                raise IndexError(key)

            return bool(bisect.bisect_right(self.changes, key) % 2)

    def _indexes(self, start, end):
        start_index = bisect.bisect_right(self.changes, start)
        end_index = bisect.bisect_right(self.changes, end)
        return start_index, end_index


    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """Sets item or slice to True or False

        >>> s = SBA(20); s[2:6] = True; s
        SparseBitArray('00111100000000000000')
        >>> s[4:10] = True; s
        SparseBitArray('00111111110000000000')
        >>> s[3:11] = False; s
        SparseBitArray('00100000000000000000')
        >>> s[4:14] = True; s
        SparseBitArray('00101111111111000000')
        >>> s[8:11] = False; s
        SparseBitArray('00101111000111000000')
        >>> s[5:7] = True; s
        SparseBitArray('00101111000111000000')
        >>> s[15:18] = False; s
        SparseBitArray('00101111000111000000')
        >>> s[14:16] = False; s
        SparseBitArray('00101111000111000000')
        >>> s[14:16] = True; s
        SparseBitArray('00101111000111110000')
        >>> s[4:] = True; s
        SparseBitArray('00101111111111111111')
        >>> s[:10] = False; s
        SparseBitArray('00000000001111111111')
        >>> s[:] = False; s
        SparseBitArray('00000000000000000000')
        >>> s[:] = True; s
        SparseBitArray('11111111111111111111')
        """
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            start, end = self._decode_slice(key)
            start_index, end_index = self._indexes(start, end)

            new_changes = self.changes[:start_index]

            if bool(len(new_changes) % 2) != value:
                new_changes.append(start)

            if bool(end_index % 2) != value:
                new_changes.append(end)

            new_changes.extend( self.changes[end_index:] )

            self.changes = new_changes
        else:
            raise ValueError("Single element assignment not allowed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    print doctest.testmod()
```